# Tier 2 visa extension

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, uk-visa

I am currently on a Tier 2 general visa that expires on 14 July 2018. I am planning to submit my application for visa extension tomorrow.

On the website they state that the new visa could take up to 8 weeks to process. Which would take me over the expiry of my current visa.

What would the implications of this be ?

1. Should I rather go for the premium service?
2. Would it affect my ILR application in two years, if my visa is not processed in time?
3. Would I be allowed to stay in the country after I submitted my application, after my current visa has expired?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, a pending application allows one to stay in the country, but I am not certain whether that applies in the UK, much less whether it applies to Tier 2 extensions.

Answer (score 1):

From the guidance: https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/extend-your-visa

> Once you’ve applied you can stay in the UK until you’ve been given a decision, as long as you applied before your last visa expired.

Assuming you do not have plans to leave the country or a need of your passport during the processing time, there is no reason to use the priority of premium services.

I forget how the start/end date of the new visa works. If the extension takes you up to the 6 year limit, then it does not really matter. Maybe it affects the health care surcharge if changes from one year to a little over a year.